Should UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration have also AuthenticationUserDetailsService in the ConditionalOnMissingBean?
I'm using a PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider in an AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter but didn't declare a bean for AuthenticationManager, AuthenticationProvider, UserDetailsServiceor AuthenticationManagerResolver; didn't want these to be configurable in my case.
I use an AuthenticationUserDetailsService and only need to have this configurable so I declare a bean for this class.
I'm building an custom autoconfiguration module for my app so my code will be used as a dependency in my app.
When I start the app the UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration is loaded and the InMemoryUserDetailsManager bean is created (loggin some security warnings), which I don't want.
I know I can disable it using spring:autoconfigure:exclude but this would be in the application.yaml of the app and I need a solution to do it in my autoconfiguration module.
So, my question is: Should UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration have also AuthenticationUserDetailsService in the ConditionalOnMissingBean ?
I would suggest to do the following change in the UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration:
change this :
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = { 
AuthenticationManager.class,AuthenticationProvider.class,
UserDetailsService.class,

with:
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = 
{ AuthenticationManager.class, AuthenticationProvider.class, 
UserDetailsService.class, AuthenticationUserDetailsService.class,

If not why?
One simple solution is to declare a bean for the AuthenticationProvider but my point is: if UserDetailsService in the the condition, shouldn't the AuthenticationUserDetailsService be there too?
One way to solve it, I have seen in other places, is to add the following bean:
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    // dummy user details service
    return username -> new User(username, "N/A", emptyList());
  }

But this it's just a workaround to avoid the default UserDetailsService to be created and it doesn't avoid the UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration to be loaded.
Is there any other way to achieve what I need to do without declaring other beans that the AuthenticationUserDetailsService?

No it shouldn't as that has nothing to do with UserDetailsService as it isn't one. What you should do is configure a PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider which will make the UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration back-off automatically. The fact that you didn't indicates you didn't make a bean for said class but instantiated it somewhere yourself.

@M.Deinum thanks a lot for the clarification!
